# Mach-O Linker Error - files Imported(and checked) properly but still error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors, linker-errors

I know there has been countless Mach-O Linker error posts and I have looked through at least a dozen trying to find the solution to my problem. Many solutions commented that I must "check the box" or check the compile sources to make sure my .m file was properly imported and yes, I did all of those. I have been at this for hours and I can't seem to make anything from the below error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_JSQMessage", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ChatView.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ChatView.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ChatView.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_JSQMessagesTimestampFormatter", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ChatView.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_JSQMessagesViewController", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_ChatView in ChatView.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_JSQPhotoMediaItem", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ChatView.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_JSQSystemSoundPlayer", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ChatView.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_JSQMessagesViewController", referenced from:
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ChatView in ChatView.o
  "_kJSQMessagesCollectionViewCellLabelHeightDefault", referenced from:
  -[ChatView collectionView:layout:heightForCellTopLabelAtIndexPath:] in ChatView.o
  -[ChatView collectionView:layout:heightForMessageBubbleTopLabelAtIndexPath:] in ChatView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any help or advice as to a fix to the above error would be MUCH appreciated and would finally allow me to move on from this gripping road block. Thank you in advance!

Comment: i have the same error .. did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when using this library through Cocoapods. I noticed this warning message when executing `pod install`:

> [!] The `Application [Debug]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS`
>   build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support
>   Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the
>   CocoaPods installation

I added `$(inherited)` to `OTHER_LDFLAGS` in the build settings of my project and that fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a relevant 'Framework'. Does the documentation specify a required framework. I would guess that it needs the messaging one.

Comment: There is a JSQMessagesViewController but all that is necessary is to bring in the folder. No framework necessary. Any ideas?